# Django router retrieve specific account

Tags: python, django, http

This code works for retrieving the entire list of accounts with localhost:8000/accounts/, but not for a specific account when given the email associated with the account (localhost:8000/accounts/[email of account]/. Instead, the data sent back is an HTML file. Sometimes if I put in an email that doesn't exist, it tells me the detail was not found. But only sometimes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are my different files:

**VIEWS.PY**

```
    class AccountViewSet(views.ModelViewSet):
        lookup_field = 'email'
        queryset = Account.objects.all()
        serializer_class = AccountSerializer
```

**URLS.PY**

```
     router = routers.SimpleRouter()
     router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)
     url patterns = [
         url(r'api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
     ]
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    objects = AccountManager()
```

Comment: What server are you working on? If it is not the development server then try to restart your webserver...

Comment: @Jingo I'm running in development off localhost. If I run command 'curl http://localhost:8000/api/v1/accounts/' with server running I'll get a list of all the accounts in the database, but if I try 'curl http://localhost:8000/api/v1/accounts/email@email.com/' if email@email.com is connected to a user I'll get an HTML page returned instead of just that account object

Answer (score 0):

I realized what was happening. The use of the '.' in the email address -so '.com' in this case- was causing url issues. The code is set up correctly, but using a period in the email as part of a url api call is not an option.